# view helper in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework

the thing is these this lines:

```
$loginUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller'=>'auth', 'action'=>'index'));
$registerUrl = $this->view->url(array('controller'=>'register', 'action'=>'index'));
```

based on rob allens' Zend_Auth login/logout tutorial (win7/apache),
are placed in a view helper, and this one:

echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'index','action'=>'add'));

is placed in the index view script.

The generated links Do work fine in LOCAL, but in REMOTE only the 3rd line works.

ANY IDEAS? Where should i look for this? wich way to follow?
I was tempt to think in the remote server conf but the 3rd line works fine, so..

thanks!

Comment: What error do you get for the first two?

Answer (score 0):

Try this helper instead of view Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url:

//simple($action, $controller = null, $module = null, array $params = null)

//so your lines will look like:

$loginUrl = $this->_helper->url->simple('index','auth');

$registerUrl = $this->_helper->url->simple('index','register');

P.S. your lines work properly on Win7 and Ubuntu servers check registry of the lines

Comment: thanks, i d tried but gives me Undefined property: Zend_View_Helper_LoggedInAs::$_helper in C:\wamp\www\test\share\application\views\helpers\LoggedInAs.php on line 29 (the new line of $loginUrl=...) on LOCAL and on REMOTE, the page is just blank (no errors displayed, i supose their are off)

Comment: are you talking about Conntroller_Action helper? This helpers you can use only at Controller or if get instance of this one. Show more code where you use $loginUrl and $registerUrl.

Comment: anyway you can get helper by this:
$helperObj = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('helperName');

Comment: i think those 2 lines are not in a view, i mean, your answer points me to further study, and i was on it today but still i not sure how to answer. the 3rd one is in a view, but the others are in a view helper that is been called from the layout...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that was the server. (.htacces and mod_rewrite) was not included in the package.
I think the third line was working because it was in the index controller, but when calling the others, then happened the object not found.

To work out this, i found an example using zend debug (was in german) so i inferred it (and then wrote to the hosting service), but still not quite sure how to check (phpinfo?) if a host have this features available or not in your package.